# Is Cartthrob 2.6 compatible with EE 2.9.0?

Tags: cartthrob, ee2-upgrades

Before I take the leap and upgrade to EE 2.9.0, I would like to make sure the CT 2.6 is compatible. Has anyone else had experience with this? Is it safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated today and did quite a lot of testing. No issues so far. They mentioned they'd been using it with the 2.9 preview.

Comment: I found an issues with the payment gateways, though I think this may only affect a few (I tested this with WorldPay). I created a fix for it to work and since then everything else seems fine.